# What are "weak reference" profile links on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

[image: Picture]

I have found nothing about of the purpose of that little icon next to a name tag (referenced by the red arrow in the picture above) from Facebook API docs. To be honest this is the first time I have seen it. It still works like a regular name tag, only difference is the mysterious icon and the greyed out name.

```
<a class="profileLink weakReference" href="facebook_profile_link" ...
```

Comment: Facebook has started giving verified status similar to twitter. It could be that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I got the answer!
No it't not because of verified account. Verifies profiles show a blue tick mark
Whereas this kind of symbol comes in the following case
When you Tag a friend in a closed group, hence that friend will not be notified of the tag nor of the notifications. Then this symbol comes before his/her name

Comment: They should add a title attribute to that icon. I suspected it had something to do with privacy settings, but it's really not obvious.